# Link a JSP file within another JSP

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

Im trying to split my JSP code up so that its not all in one file. I have 2 tabs - Home and Test. Here is my code:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#tabHome">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#test">Test</a></li>
</ul>
```

The problem is that when the home tab loads, it also loads the test page. Here is how i link to the test page:

```
<div id="test">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <jsp:include page="test.jsp" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</div>
```

and the test.jsp:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div>
        <table width="100%" border="0">
        <col width="14%">
            <form:form id="testForm" method="post" action="/test/testing
            <tr>
                <td> SYSTEM SETTINGS </td>
            </tr>
            </form:form>
         </table>
         </div>
     </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I get it to only show the test.jsp when the tab is clicked?

Comment: So basically you're looking for deferred rending of the test page?

Comment: whatever you write in JSP page, JAVA Code will be convert to html code when the page is called. This conversion of java code to html is done by Server. If you want a tabbing kind of functionality and stay on same page. You can use Javascript function that calls a function on clicking "Home" / "Test" Tabs and append the Iframe tag of home/test jsp page.

Comment: @Varun Achar yes I would like to do deferred rendering I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anchor href's of the form #name point to content on the same page. you'll need Javascript to show the tab you just clicked on and hide the other one.

Alternatively, you could have the second tab on another page: 
Common code linking to tabs in separate JSPs:

tabs.jsp:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="/path/to/tabHome.jsp">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="/path/to/test.jsp">Test</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then other JSPs would all include tabs.jsp to show the tabset so it would look the same on all pages.

Comment: Thanks for this. Seems to work well but how do you hide the tab once you click off it?

Comment: Wrap the contents of each tab in a div element, and use the CSS property display:none on them. Then, when you click on a tab, have javascript remove the display:none from the tab you want to display, and re-apply it to all others. Example here : http://www.my-html-codes.com/javascript-tabs-html-5-css3